# How to split a string of repeated characters with uneven amounts? Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split

If I have a string such as `"aabbbbccdddeffffgg"` and I wanted to split the string into this array: `["aa", "bbbb", "cc", "ddd", "e", "ffff", "gg"]`, how would I go about that?

I know of `string.split/.../` < or however many period you put there, but it doesn't account for if the strings are uneven. The point of the problem I'm working on is to take two strings and see if there are three characters in a row of one string and two in a row in the other. I tried

```
  `letter_count_1 = {}
    str1.each_char do |let|
       letter_count_1[let] = str1.count(let)
    end`
```

But that gives the count for the total amount of each character in the string, and some of the inputs are randomized with the same letter in multiple places, like, `"aabbbacccdba"`

So how do you split the string up by character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex with a back reference and the `scan()` method:

```
str = "aabbbbccdddeffffgg"
groups = []
str.scan(/((.)\2*)/) { |x| groups.push(x[0]) }
```

`groups` will look like this afterwards:

```
["aa", "bbbb", "cc", "ddd", "e", "ffff", "gg"]
```

Comment: @sawa I'm (unfortunately) not really a ruby coder. I just found it fun to solve this. Let me check your suggestion...

Comment: @sawa Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: `str.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first)`.

Comment: Ruby is nice! :) Someday I might have a chance to work with it ... Feel free to add that to my answer or post your own.. Having the list as the return value of that chained command is truly a benefit since we wouldn't need to initialize it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a non-regexp version

```
str = "aabbbbccdddeffffgg"
p str.chars.chunk(&:itself).map{|x|x.last.join} #=> ["aa", "bbbb", "cc", "ddd", "e", "ffff", "gg"]
```

Comment: With Ruby v2.3.0 you use [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while): `str.each_char.chunk_while { |curr,nxt| curr==nxt }.map(&:join)
 #=> ["aa", "bbbb", "cc", "ddd", "e", "ffff", "gg"]`. [Enumerable.slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (from v2.2) is similar. I would also suggest `each_char` over `chars` to avoid creating the temporary array.

Comment: Amazing! Nice one!